# Using Django Rest Framework with a normalized database

Tags: rest, django-models, django-rest-framework, relational-database

The basic use case of DRF seems to be that there is a one-to-one mapping of "resources" (on API side) to tables (on the database side).

Specifically, let's say we have "Locale" entity that contains one or more "Projects": The "Locale" represents common geographic and administrative information across a set of Projects -- if it changes for one, we need to change for all.

Instead of a denormalized Locale + Projects table that combines both, we represent this in normalized form as `Locale` and `Projects` tables in our database, using "Locale ID" as a foreign key in our `Projects` table. However, we want this normalization to be hidden from the api users -- we just want to expose a `/project/` endpoint that returns the `Project` data joined with the associated `Locale` data as if it were coming from the denormalized table.

How can I represent a single API resource in DRF when it is composed of multiple models (and hence tables) on the backend database?

**Technical notes**:

- My backend in posgtresql 9.6
- This is not a transactional database, so we expect updates on the order of 10-15 per day, not 100's per second.

---

## My ideas so far

**(1)** ***Create a materialized view on back end that does the join and then create an unmanaged model in Django that exists soley to support GET requests.***

**PROS**: Seems to best mesh with Django/DRF use case, since I'm just
    creating another table and model (albeit with read-only functionality).

**CONS**: I'll need to refresh the materialized view to after every update if I want to ensure users see their changes to the underlying data (e.g., change some info in locale). I will probably use REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY to at least allow the view to function while updating.

So, +1 for ease of implementation, -1 for currency.

**(2)** ***Use raw parameterized SQL queries on back end to set up JOIN and return results.***

PROS: Avoids issues with refreshing materialized views after updates.

CONS: Seems tricky to accommodate complex querie -- I see this could become brittle.

***(3) Denormalize so we have a `LocaleProjects` table***

PROS: Easy.

CONS: Data consistency is compromised. Need to write additional backend queries to update records that share a locale if the locale record is changed.

Any additional inputs would be helpful.

Comment: "The basic use case of DRF seems to be that there is a one-to-one mapping of "resources" (on API side) to tables (on the database side)." That is just not so. Why do you think that?

Comment: @philipxy the serializers are built around models, which are built around tables. I don't see much that shows how to create a model that actually represents a join of two tables. That's why. I'd be very happy if I am wrong and someone can educate me on how DRF can handle cases where a resource is represented as a join of several tables in the underlying database.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use the `Project` model as your base model, and the `Locale` related fields as complementary fields. Following an example for the `ListAPIView`. If you need create or update endpoints to update `Project` and `Locale` at the same time as if you had a denormalized table, you can override the `create` and the `update` functions.

I assume that the `locale` field is a `ForeignKey` from `Project` to `Locale`.

In your `serializers.py`:

```
class ProjectWithLocaleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    locale_field_1 = serializers.XXXField(source='locale.field_1')
    locale_field_2 = serializers.XXXField(source='locale.field_2')

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('project_field_1', 'project_field_2', 'locale_field_1', 'locale_field_2', )
```

In your `views.py`:

```
class ProjectWithLocaleListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    model = Project
    serializer_class = ProjectWithLocaleSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.select_related('locale')
```